# Error WF but no errors on WF

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I save and publish my WF and appears this

[image]

if i check the WF have errors but appears no have it

[image]

What happened? I cant execute it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, troubleshoot as following:

1. [Clear SharePoint Designer cache](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33469.how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache.aspx) and then run IISreset .
2. Increase the UserDefinedWorkflowMaximumComplexity to 10000  setting using SharePoint 2010 Management Shell:

   $app = get-spwebapplication http://sp

   $app.UserDefinedWorkflowMaximumComplexity = 10000

   $app.Update()